# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str' when using . pct_change()

Tags: string

My code is very simple. I imported a .csv file with daily prices of 10 different indices. Then it looks like this

[image: TVOL_Port.head()]

When using the code

```
TVOL_Port.pct_change()
```

I get the error message from the title. Obviously the prices aren't floats but strings but other functions like .describe(), .cov(), .corr() and so on work fine.
I used the same numbers in another jupyter notebooks where it worked fine as well but there I only used one column instead of 10 in this example.

If I am right, and all prices are strings, how can I convert them into floats? I am beginner in programming. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by indexing the first column 'date'.